# Populating select list from database PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Having trouble with a script.. I have tried different solutions without solving this issue. I'm not good at Javascript so it's probably in the javascript i have an issue..

I'm trying to populate a secondary select list with options in regard to a previous choice. I think my code so far is pretty straight forward.

Thanks in advance!

**HTML** page.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
  $("#second-choice").load("get.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
</script>

<select id="first-choice">
  <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<br>

<select id="second-choice">
  <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

**PHP** get.php

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

    $choice = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);
    $results = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE parentcat='$choice'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row{'subcat'} . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['choice'])` that alone is failing here.

Comment: That was a blazing fast answer dude! What's wrong with it? Shouldn't i escape the get? Or am i just doing it wrong?

Comment: `$choice = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['choice']);` it needs a connection for that function.

Comment: Thanks again for a fast reply. Although that did not fix my problem. It still doesn't work. But i appreciate the fix! Something else is bugging though..